# p4api.net SyncFiles Progress

Tags: perforce, progress, p4api.net

Is it possible wit p4api.net to SyncFiles (Get Latest) from perforce and have progress indicator similar to one from P4V?

Thanks for any idea!

[image]

Comment: I don't think P4API.NET supports this.  I'd expect to see some kind of `ProgressDelegate` that you can set in the `P4Server` object, but there's no clue anywhere in the docs of such a thing existing.